# Como faço para passar a altura de uma div para outra?

Tags: javascript, css, div, layout-responsivo

Eu estou com este problema: o texto fica responsivo, porém, como faço para que a div em vermelho fique do mesmo tamanho que a div cinza ao lado, conforme diminuo e aumento a tela? Existe uma solução com *CSS* ou com *JS*? E se tem, como faço?

[image: divs coloridas]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            padding: 0px;margin: 0px;
        }
        section{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: pink;
            display: table;
        }
        #red, #gray{
            width: 45%;
            float: left;
            padding-right: 2.5%;
            padding-left: 2.5%;
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 50px;
        }
        #red{
            background-color: red;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #gray{
            background-color: gray;
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }
        #green{
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            clear: both;
            background-color: green;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div id="red">
        É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas.
        </div>
        <div id="gray">
            É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas da Web agora usam o Lorem Ipsum como seu texto de modelo padrão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" descobrirá muitos sites da Web ainda em sua infância. Várias versões evoluíram ao longo dos anos, às vezes por acidente, às vezes de propósito (humor injetado e coisas do gênero).
        </div>
    </section>
    <div id="green">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vc pode trocar o `display:table` por `display:flex` no elemento Pai. E depois basta remover o `heigth:100%` dos elementos filhos, pois agora eles serão filhos de um pai flex.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o código como fica

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;margin: 0px;
}
section{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
}
#red, #gray{
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#red{
    background-color: red;
    /* height: 100%; */
}
#gray{
    background-color: gray;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
#green{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="red">
    É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas.
    </div>
    <div id="gray">
        É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas da Web agora usam o Lorem Ipsum como seu texto de modelo padrão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" descobrirá muitos sites da Web ainda em sua infância. Várias versões evoluíram ao longo dos anos, às vezes por acidente, às vezes de propósito (humor injetado e coisas do gênero).
    </div>
</section>
<div id="green">
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa! Que resposta! Salvou meu dia, obrigada, e espero que essa resposta ajude a todos que estiverem com a mesma duvida! <3 <3

Comment: Como eu faço se eu precisar de mais div dentro dessas divs, e nao quero que todas sejam flex? pq pelo que vi se eu colocar  div dentro de div da um erro visual

Comment: @Miriam ai vai depender do layout que vc pretende montar. Procure no Google por Guia flexbox ou tutorial flexbox que vc vai achar muito material. Pra vc ter uma ideia o grid de layout do próprio Bootstrap eh feito com Flex, pois o Flex eh muito responsivo e tem varias classes de alinhamento , mas vc vai precisar de uma horinha para estuda-lo para entender

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar `display: table-cell;` nas divs `red` e `gray`, já que a section está com `display: table`. Isso fará com que as divs (e a section) se comportem como se fossem uma table. Agora, é preciso retirar o `float: left` senão não funcionará (repare que comentei algumas propriedades desnecessárias):

```css
*{
   padding: 0px;margin: 0px;
}
section{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: pink;
   display: table;
}
#red, #gray{
   width: 45%;
   /* float: left; */
   padding-right: 2.5%;
   padding-left: 2.5%;
   padding-top: 50px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   display: table-cell;
}
#red{
   background-color: red;
   /* height: 100%; */
}
#gray{
   background-color: gray;
}
#green{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   clear: both;
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div id="red">
      É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas.
   </div>
   <div id="gray">
      É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas da Web agora usam o Lorem Ipsum como seu texto de modelo padrão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" descobrirá muitos sites da Web ainda em sua infância. Várias versões evoluíram ao longo dos anos, às vezes por acidente, às vezes de propósito (humor injetado e coisas do gênero).
   </div>
</section>
<div id="green">
</div>
```

### Usando JavaScript

O que você pode fazer é colocar `height: 100%` nas duas divs, porém, para esse height funcionar, a section precisa ter uma altura definida em pixels (`px`), caso contrário o height fica sem referência. No entanto, você não pode definir uma altura fixa da section no CSS porque a altura das divs podem variar na responsividade.

Com JavaScript você pode ajustar a altura da section de forma dinâmica em dois eventos, no carregamento da página e ao redimensionar a tela. Mas para isso é preciso corrigir algumas coisas no seu CSS.

Primeiro retire o `display: table` da section, e o `box-sizing: content-box;` é redundante porque o valor `content-box` já é o valor default da propriedade `box-sizing`. Portanto, pode retirá-la também.

Adicione o `height: 100%` nas duas divs, `#red` e `#gray`. Outra coisa é colocar os textos dentro de parágrafos `<p></p>`, ficando assim:

```
<section>
   <div id="red">
      <p>É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gray">
      <p>É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas da Web agora usam o Lorem Ipsum como seu texto de modelo padrão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" descobrirá muitos sites da Web ainda em sua infância. Várias versões evoluíram ao longo dos anos, às vezes por acidente, às vezes de propósito (humor injetado e coisas do gênero).</p>
   </div>
</section>
<div id="green">
</div>
```

São esses `<p>` que servirão de referência para ajustar a altura da section, pois eles irão variar de altura à medida que a tela é redimensionada. Aí, pelo JS, basta ajustar a altura da section pelo `<p>` que for maior:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   var red = document.getElementById("red");
   var gray = document.getElementById("gray");
   var section = document.querySelector("section");
   
   function ajusta(){
      var p_red = red.querySelector("p").clientHeight;
      var p_gray = gray.querySelector("p").clientHeight;
      
      section.style.height = (p_red < p_gray ? p_gray : p_red) +"px";
         
   }

   window.onresize = ajusta;
   ajusta();
   
});
```

```css
*{
   padding: 0px;margin: 0px;
}
section{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: pink;
   /* display: table; */
}
#red, #gray{
   width: 45%;
   float: left;
   padding-right: 2.5%;
   padding-left: 2.5%;
   padding-top: 50px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   height: 100%;
}
#red{
   background-color: red;
}
#gray{
   background-color: gray;
   /* box-sizing: content-box; */
}
#green{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   clear: both;
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div id="red">
      <p>É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gray">
      <p>É um fato há muito estabelecido que um leitor se distrairá com o conteúdo legível de uma página ao analisar seu layout. O ponto de usar o Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma distribuição de letras mais ou menos normal, em vez de usar 'Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo aqui', fazendo com que pareça legível em inglês. Muitos editores de editoração eletrônica e editores de páginas da Web agora usam o Lorem Ipsum como seu texto de modelo padrão, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" descobrirá muitos sites da Web ainda em sua infância. Várias versões evoluíram ao longo dos anos, às vezes por acidente, às vezes de propósito (humor injetado e coisas do gênero).</p>
   </div>
</section>
<div id="green">
</div>
```

Comment: UAU! Funcionou tambem! Muito obrigada mesmo!!!!

Comment: De nada! O ruim do flex é que ele não funciona em alguns navegadores.

Answer (score 0):

Basta apenas por a altura nas duas:

```
#red, #gray{
    height: ..;
}
```